# Is it possible to rename a worksheet using ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I am getting files from an outside vender where the third worksheet is always titled differently (one month is has a date, the next month it has initials and a date, the next month could have just initials or the name of someone cat, etc). In order to process it, I need to change the name. Here is what I've tried per this blog post: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/03/27/win32ole-and-ruby-working-with-worksheets/

```
require 'win32ole'

excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = true

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\MyTest.xlsx');

worksheet = workbook.worksheets(2);

worksheet.name = 'NewChanges'
workbook.Saved = true;

excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0);
excel.Quit()
```

Doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had an incorrect save. Should have been

```
workbook.Save
```